# PHP Zend (ZF1) cant change StringLength messages in Zend_Filter_Input

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have a problem with changing messages for StringLength in Zend_Filter_Input.      Code:

```
    $filters = array(
        'nazwa'   => 'StringTrim',
        'haslo'   => 'StringTrim'
    );           

    $validators = array(
        'nazwa'   => array(
            'allowEmpty' => false,                  
            'presence' => 'required',                       
            new Zend_Validate_StringLength(array('min' => 5, 'max' => 30)),
            array('Regex', array('pattern' => '/^[\w]+$/'))
        ),
        'haslo'   => array(
            'allowEmpty' => false,              
            'presence' => 'required',
            new Zend_Validate_StringLength(array('min' => 5, 'max' => 30))
        )
    );              

    $data = array(
        'nazwa'   => $formData['nazwa'],
        'haslo'   => $formData['haslo']
        );              

     $options = array(
            'notEmptyMessage' => "Pole '%field%' jest wymagane"
         );

    $input = new Zend_Filter_Input($filters, $validators, $data, $options);
```

I think I just tried everything from translating, adding options, messages in $validators and it is still default message. Please let me know how to change those default error messages (like TOO_SHORT, TOO_LONG) for new ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set message for validator failure.

```
$validator = new Zend_Validate_StringLength();
$validator->setMessage(
  'Your cusom message about short string',
  Zend_Validate_StringLength::TOO_SHORT
);
```

Then add `$validator` to your `$validators`.

More information [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/ru/zend.validate.messages.html).